# Firefox Marketplace - How to sibmit several games published on the same domain?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firefox-addon, manifest

We’ve been trying to submit 5 of our games to the Firefox Marketplace, but unfortunately we succeeded only with one, which is currently waiting for the review. 
Afterwards we faced an issue with inability to add other games because they are published on the same domain - our game portal, plarium.com. Following manifest URLs [haven't been validated](http://screencast.com/t/nmwMj4rqrk2):
[image]

Is it required to use one domain for each game or is there another solution we can proceed with?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not related to programming.

Comment: If I understand the question, you have to change your manifest. In the manifest (`package.json`) of your addons, you have to change the value of `id` property. This property must be unique

Comment: Its related to Firefox addons @rob i dont know which other tag they would be able to put this question. The firefox addon users are the ones who know how to upload addons, which is similar method for web apps on the Firefox marketplace.

Comment: @Noitidart This question has nothing to do with programming which puts it off-topic for SO. The question is about submission method for a game as a Firefox add-on.

Comment: @Rob, It appears that it might fall within the "software tools commonly used by programmers" portion of what is [on topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is asking about a tool that is being used exclusively by programmers to publish their work. The tool being asked about has no other function that is not related to programming (i.e. publishing applications). I'm willing to be convinced either way, but I am not seeing that it is clearly off-topic due to not being related to programming.